# Finding the Hecke grossencharachter of a CM newform

Tags: modular-forms, complex-multiplication

The definition of "newform with CM" I'm interested in is given on p. 415 of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cdm/1254748659). You start by specifying your imaginary quadratic field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ for $D < 0$, an integer $k \geq 2$, and a Hecke character $c: I(\mathfrak{f}_{c}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ of conductor $\mathfrak{f}_{c} \subset \mathcal{O}_{K}$. Here,

$$c(\alpha \mathcal{O}_{K}) = \alpha^{k-1}, \quad \text{for } \alpha \equiv 1 \hspace{-2ex} \mod \mathfrak{f}_{c}.$$

We get a Dirichlet character $\omega_{c}$ given by

$$\omega_{c}(n) := \frac{c(n \mathcal{O}_{K})}{n^{k-1}}, \quad \text{for } n \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ coprime to } \mathfrak{f}_{c}.$$

We also have the usual character $\chi_{K} := \left( \frac{D}{*} \right)$. Now our CM newform is

$$\Phi_{K, c}(z) := \sum_{\mathfrak{a}} c(\mathfrak{a})q^{N(\mathfrak{a})} \in S_{k}\left(|D|N(\mathfrak{f}_{c}), \chi_{K}\cdot\omega_{c}\right),$$

where the sum runs over integral ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ of $K$ prime to $\mathfrak{f}_{c}$, and where $N$ is the usual ideal norm.

**Example:** Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, $k = 2$. Note that $\omega_{c}$ is trivial. I choose $\mathfrak{f}_{c} := (3) \subset \mathcal{O}_{K}$. I can only guess what my Hecke character $c$ should be... **that's what I need help with**. Here, $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ is a PID. My newform with CM should then look something like

$$\sum_{a \not\equiv b \hspace{0.5ex}(3)} \left(a + \frac{b}{2}(1 + \sqrt{-3})\right)q^{a^{2} + ab + b^{2}},$$

or at least I think it should. Note that it lies in $S_{2}(27)$. The problem I now have is that I'd get cancellation with $a + \frac{b}{2}(1 + \sqrt{-3})$ and $-a - \frac{b}{2}(1 + \sqrt{-3})$ in my sum, making the whole thing zero. Fine -- I did something wrong with the coefficients. It seems to come down to choosing the representative that $c$ spits out when inputing the ideal $\left(a + \frac{b}{2}(1 + \sqrt{-3})\right)$. I know that this form should look like

$$q - 2q^{4} - q^{7} + 5q^{13} + \cdots.$$

Comment: You need to start with a Hecke character, and $c(z)=z,z\in O_K,K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ is not because it is not trivial on $O_K^\times$. You can try $c(z)= z \chi(z)^{-1}$ where $\chi$ is the homomorphism $O_K/(7,\zeta_3-2)\to 0\cup \langle \zeta_6\rangle$, or $c(z)=z^6/|z|^5$.

Comment: @reuns I'm a little confused on what you typed. Are you saying that $c$ IS or is NOT trivial in my example? I would think that $c \mid_{\mathcal{O}_{K}} = id_{\mathcal{O}_{K}}$, in which case $\omega_{c} \equiv 1$. Thanks.

Comment: $c(z)=z$ is not a Hecke character : $c(z)\ne c(-z)$ which means $c(z O_K)$ is ill defined. The Hecke characters are those characters on the group of fractional ideals that have a continuous extension to the ideles (ie. they can be expressed in term of local places and residue rings)

Comment: @reuns Yes, I agree. This is the problem I'm having. Is there an "easy" way to specify $c$ with just the information given in the example?

Comment: If you want to build a newform with trivial character, you can't expect $\omega_c$ to be trivial; it has to be $\chi_K^{-1}$. This might give you a hint at what $c$ has to be.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Hmm okay this is a good hint.. thanks.